# How to Implement Command Line CURL into PHP CURL Request

Tags: php, curl, command-line

I want to Implement following Command Line CURL into PHP CURL Request.

```
curl --data username=ekansh&domain=siteURL&password=mypass
http://siteURL:8090/add-user -k -v -u  apiuser:yru3472825fhj
```

I have tried below code for the same:

```
    $fields = array('domain'=> 'siteURL','password'=> 'mypass','apiuser'=> 
'yru3472825fhj','username'=> 'ekansh');
    $data=>array(CURLOPT_POST => 1,CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,CURLOPT_URL => 
$url,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 
1,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($_POST));
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $options=$fields+$defaults;
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $result=curl_exec($ch) 
    curl_close($ch);
```

But this is not working .. i am not getting any response in $result. How could i will implement above code?

**UPDATE**

```
    $fields = array('domain'  => 'siteurl','password' => 'mypass',
'apiuser'=> 'yru3472825fhj','username'=> 'ekansh');
    $data=array(CURLOPT_POST => 1,CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,CURLOPT_URL => 
    'siteurl',CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields);
    $ch = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$data);   
    $result=curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

I have modified above code but it still not working.

Comment: Several thing. 1) `+` does not seem to work on arrays; 2) You may mistakenly set curl options to `$options` instead of `$data`.

Comment: @Passerby Please see above Update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$data` array, it should be:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields
```

And to set all the options it should be:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, $data);
```

This line doesn't do anything:

```
$options = $fields + $defaults;
```

You can't use `+` on arrays, and you never set `$defaults`.

For authentication, you need to use the option:

```
CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'apiuser:yru3472825fhj'
```

instead of putting them in `$data`.

Comment: See additional answer regarding authentication.